# Facing an Error in Visualforce Page. Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I am trying to implement Type Ahead Search functionality.
Please refer the below code lines, I am facing an error as Uncaught Reference Error: controller(PredictiveSearchController) not defined

**

- Visual Force Page

**

```
<apex:page controller="PredictiveSearchController">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js" />
      <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" />
  <apex:outputtext >Welcome to Predictive Search</apex:outputtext>

  <apex:form id="conFrm" >
  <apex:pageblock title="Seach an Contact">
      <table class="detailList">
          <tr>
              <td >
                  Contact Name
              </td>
              <td>
                  <div id="ContactSearchContainer" style="position: relative;">
                      <input type="Text" id="contactSearch" class="ContactInput"/>
                      <div id="contactSearchDropDown" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 19px; left: 2px; border: 1px solid gray; width: 400px; height: 150px; background: white; overflow-y: scroll;">
                          <table style="padding:  0px; margin: 5px 0 0 0;">
                              <tbody id="ContactSearchList">
                              </tbody>                     
                          </table>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>  
  </apex:pageblock>
 </apex:form>
    <Script type="Text/JavaScript">
        var typingTimer;
        var doneTypingInterval = 900;
        $('input.ContactInput').keyup(function(){
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);
            typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
        }); 

        function doneTyping () {
            console.log('reached to call predictivesearch');
            predictiveSearchKeyUp('Contact'); 
        }

        $('input.ContactInput').keydown(function(){
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        });

        function predictiveSearchKeyUp(searchType){
        console.log('test');
            var inputElement = $('input.'+searchType+'Input')[0];
            var inputText = inputElement.value;
            var searchDropdown = $('#'+searchType+'SearchDropdown');
            var searchList = searchDropdown.find('#'+searchType+'SearchList');
            var minChars = searchType == 'Contact' ? 2 : 1;

            if (inputText.length < minChars) {
                    searchDropdown.hide(250);
                return;
            }
            console.log(inputText );
            **Error Here** Uncaught ReferenceError: PredictiveSearchController not defined*  PredictiveSearchController.findAuthorsByName(inputText, function(result, event){
                console.log(inputText);
                if (event.status && document.activeElement.className == 'ContactInput') {
                    searchList.html('');
                    $.each(result, function(key, author){
                            searchList.append('<tr><td style="padding: 2px;"><a onClick="authorClicked(\'' + author.id + '\', \'' + author.name + '\')" style="cursor: pointer;">'+author.name+'</td>  </tr>');
                        });
                    searchDropdown.show(250);
                }                
            }, {escape:false});


        }


    </Script>

</apex:page>
```

**

- Controller Class

**

```
global class PredictiveSearchController {


    global static List<Contact> findAuthorsByName( string startWith){

            System.debug('Entered Here');
            List<contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
            string containParam = '%' + startWith + '%';
            contacts = [select id, name, email
                        From Contact 
                        where Name like :containParam 
                        order by Name
                        limit 25];

        return contacts;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Javascript remoting so you need to define your method with `@RemoteAction` attribute

```
@RemoteAction
global static List<Contact> findAuthorsByName( string startWith){
 //other code here
```

You can check more about [Remoting here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm).

Also you can call your remoting method as

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.AccountRemoter.getAccount}',
            accountName, 
            function(result, event){
```

Where `AccountRemoter` is class Name and `getAccount` is method name and `accountName` is parameter.

Comment: Its working thanks, but in the drop down it always showing undefined for all the records

Comment: @RanjeetKumar that you can put as another question also if this solve your problem you can accept this answer.

Comment: Answer is accepted, now it can call the controller but not able to show the contact names in vf page.

Comment: @RanjeetKumar you can post that another question and tag me.